# PyQt - make window top level

Tags: pyqt, window

i need to make my window top level when i need.
Code of creating window:

```
class Application(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None, Qt.Tool | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_QuitOnClose, True)
```

And when i need i do:

```
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

But after running this part of code my window hides... I don't know, where is it. But my program doesn't close!
Help! How can i make my window top most at need moment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling .show() or .raise() on your window should make it top focus.

And [from the doc for setWindowFlags()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop):

> Note: This function calls setParent()
>   when changing the flags for a window,
>   causing the widget to be hidden. You
>   must call show() to make the widget
>   visible again..

I just wanted to add for anyone else who finds this question that the Qt doc for C++ is a very good resource even when using PyQt, just make sure you point to the version of the Qt C++ doc that applies to your version of PyQt (The latest PyQt is compiled against 4.4 if that is what you are using).

Comment: ``window.raise_()`` does not work for me on Linux and PyQt 4.8.3, Is it a bug?